# Type Definition for JSON file Keys with Prefix using TypeScript

Tags: json, typescript, object

I'm importing a JSON file into my TypeScript program like so: (I have enabled `resolveJsonModule` in my `tsconfig.json`)

```js
import data from './sample.json';
```

Happily, I noticed that the object received from the JSON file is strongly typed. I then wrote a function which accesses a certain key of said JSON object based on a parameter:

```js
export const get = (key: keyof typeof data): void => {
    console.log(data[key]); // example code
};
```

This works as expected, and consumers of my function get to know what values are accepted/included in the JSON file. Here comes the problem: I want consumers of my function to only be able to access certain keys which I've prefixed (in the following example the prefix is `prefix_`):

```js
export const get = (key: keyof typeof data): void => {
    console.log(data[`prefix_${key}`]);
};
```

How do I have to change my type definition so this will still work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Prior to TypeScript 4.3

There's no way as of TypeScript 4.2 to do a conditional type where you use a string function, so I don't know of a way to specify a key that starts with a prefix.

The best I can come up with uses the [Pick utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) to create a new type from the intersection of all possible properties and the derived types of the json files.

In the example below I import two sample json files.  Next, I specify all the possible keys to keep in a string literal type.  Then two types are created from the two files using *Pick*.  In order for *Pick* to work I have to pass a type in the second parameter that is the intersection of the keys of the derived file type and *PublicPrefix* type.

```
import data1 from './sample1.json'; // { x: 1, prefix_A: 2, prefix_B: 3 }
import data2 from './sample2.json'; // { y: 1, prefix_B: 2, prefix_C: 3 }
type PublicPrefix = 'prefix_A' | 'prefix_B' | 'prefix_C';
export type Data1 = Pick<typeof data1, keyof typeof data1 & PublicPrefix>;
// Data1 = { prefix_A: number, prefix_B: number }
export type Data2 = Pick<typeof data2, keyof typeof data2 & PublicPrefix>;
// Data2 = { prefix_B: number, prefix_C: number }
```

If data1 has properties *prefix_A* and *prefix_B*, and data2 has the properties *prefix_B* and *prefix_C*, then the resulting types would be `Data1 = { prefix_A, prefix_B }` and `Data2 = { prefix_B, prefix_C }` with all other keys being excluded.

### Template String Literals in TypeScript 4.3

TypeScript 4 introduced Template String Literals, and in version 4.3 they've enhanced the functionality so you can specify a contextually typed template.  This allows you to specify a type in the template which broadens those portions of the template to be anything valid for the type.

In the example below a template string literal is created that starts with *prefix_* and is followed by any string.  By using **Pick** in the same fashion as the above example, the resulting type will only contain the properties that begin with *prefix_*.

```
import data from './sample.json';
type PublicPrefix = `prefix_${string}`;
export type Data1 = Pick<typeof data, keyof typeof data & PublicPrefix>;
```